# JPA/Hibernate unable to generate the primary key in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have inherited the common properties from base entity, the id is one of the common property, I am using Generation strategy Identity.

I am trying to save child entity, but I am encountering an error where Hibernate is unable to populate primary key.

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseImagesAndLayout {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String displayName;

    @Column(name = "FILE_NAME")
    private String fileName;

 }
```

Child Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="VEHICLE_HEADER_IMAGES")
public class VehicleHeaderImage extends BaseImagesAndLayout {

    @Column(name = "MODEL_CODE")
    private String modelCode;
}
```

Saving the entity:

```
    for(S3Object object:AppUtil.skipFirst(objList)) {
                vehicleHeaderImage=new VehicleHeaderImage();
//              response = s3Service.downloadDocument(bucketName,object.key());
                response =s3Service.getDocPresignedUrl(bucketName, object.key(), null); 
                System.out.println("rsponse----"+response);
                System.out.println("filename----"+FilenameUtils.removeExtension(FilenameUtils.getName(object.key()))+ ""+FilenameUtils.getExtension(object.key()) );
                vehicleHeaderImage.setDisplayName(AppUtil.removeFileExtension(AppUtil.getFileNameFromPath(object.key())));
                vehicleHeaderImage.setFileName(vehicleHeaderImage.getDisplayName());
                vehicleHeaderImage.setModelCode("");
                vehicleHeaderImage.setS3BucketKey(object.key());
                vehicleHeaderImage.setS3PresignedUri(response.getS3DocPresignedUrl());
                headerImgRepository.save(vehicleHeaderImage);
//              vehicleHeaderImage.setS3PresignedExpDate(response.getS3DocPresignedUrlExpDt());
            }
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TRV_MASTER_DEV"."VEHICLE_HEADER_IMAGES"."ID")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:970)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3756)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3736)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1063)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: Error : 1400, Position : 0, Sql = insert into vehicle_header_images (s3_bucket_key, s3_object_uri, s3_presigned_exp_date, s3_presigned_uri, display_name, file_name, model_code) values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 ), OriginalSql = insert into vehicle_header_images (s3_bucket_key, s3_object_uri, s3_presigned_exp_date, s3_presigned_uri, display_name, file_name, model_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), Error Msg = ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TRV_MASTER_DEV"."VEHICLE_HEADER_IMAGES"."ID")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513)
    ... 130 more
```

usually hibernate take care of generation of id column, but I am unable to figured out here, one more thing to be noted is, I have created those tables using liquibase.

and I am using JPA for crud.

Comment: You need to show your DDL for creating the table

Comment: I am very much surprised, it first select all the rows from the table on the basis of Id and after that it will insert the rows, ideally, it should insert the record so only insert query executed, why select query executed, I have no idea

Comment: Why are you using GenerationType.IDENTITY with Oracle? The IDENTITY object must exist in the db, and since you are creating the database with Liquidbase, ensure you've set it up correctly in the scripts you've given it. Generally, sequences are used on Oracle, not identity, so I suspect you've created tables without it on the table